# Blend: create a group of ToggleButton: only one checked at a time

Tags: wpf, user-interface, user-controls, expression-blend, blend

In Blend for Visual Studio: 
How can I create a Group of ToggleButtons, in which only one ToggleButton at a time is checked or none?

- I tried using RadioButtons and edited their Template to make them look like ToggleButtons. But what should I group them into, that only one of them (or none) is checked?
- I also tried to create a Listbox and use ToggleButtons as items, but that didn't work either.

If there is no other way, maybe someone can give an easy explanation how to work with one of the solutions that I tried.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should use RadioButtons, because this is exactly what they are made for. RadioButtons in a common Panel are grouped automatically. If you want to group them manually, you can set their `GroupName` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should use RadioButtons and set the `Style` property as `ToggleButton`

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

All `RadioButtons`in a Panel (e.g. `StackPanel`) are grouped automatically. Therefore if one `RadioButton` is checked all others will uncheck.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Windows XP" IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Windows Vista" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Windows 7" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In case you want to group `RadioButtons` in a common Panel, you can divide them by setting different `GroupNames` like below:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows XP" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows Vista" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows 7" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2007" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2003"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Open Office"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This will devide "Office" and "OS" `RadioButtons` as two separate groups in the same panel.

Comment: Thank you very much. With the Stack Panel and a groupname it worked!

Comment: the issue with this solution is that you bypass the theme (e.g. DevExpress or something). Any idea to do the same thing while keeping current theme?

Answer (score 0):

Since RadioButton inherits ToggleButton you can use grouping functionality of the RadioButton and revert back toggle functionality that was overridden by RadioButton to it's original ToggleButton behaviour.

```
public class ToggleRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    protected override void OnToggle()
    {
        if (IsChecked == true) IsChecked = IsThreeState ? (bool?)null : (bool?)false;
        else IsChecked = IsChecked.HasValue;
    }
}
```